# How can I immigrate to Germany or Canada from Iran?

Tags: germany, immigration, canada, sweden

I own a bachelor's degree in Software Engineering, and currently work as an IT expert in a private company in Iran. Considering that my dear country, Iran, is very isolated right now (and as it seems, it will remain under crippling sanctions for the foreseeable future), how can I get out of Iran and immigrate to Europe (Germany, Sweden, etc) or Canada? I'm 27, single and I have an intermediate level of English. Where should I start and what should I do?

Comment: What research have you done up to now?

Comment: It is unclear what is your motivation to immigrate to Europe (btw., the countries in Europe are really different) or Canada. What do you want to achieve with moving to another country? Is the isolation of your motherland the only condition you are not satisfied with? How does these isolation and sanctions affect you personally now? Are you not allowed to travel or what? Why do you write "my dear country" in a sarcastic manner, do you think other countries are much better than your motherland (does not you insult yourself by writing something like this)?

Comment: Your English is clearly far better than 'Intermediate'.... While this site is great for helping with specific scenarios and technical questions, broad questions like this are impossible to answer as there are simply an infinite number of possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

If you have outstanding skills and hold a very strong job profile, you would be able to apply for a job and get a work visa in European countries and after few years receive a PR status.

If you also considering Canada, gain a Master degree and an upper band IELTS test result then go for Express Entry.

Either way, you need to be a good asset for the destination country. If you are not that good, don’t go! since you are unlikely to find a proper job and a good living (comparing what you may have in Iran).

Some people seek asylem or refugee status based on lies. This is a fast way to get there BUT your problems starts immediately. You can’t work, own anything and simply live!!!! no one will respect you there as you are being seen as a burden. Besides, developed countries has made this route harder to prevent possible system abuse, and by hard I mean you will experience very bad conditions in refugee camps and even after your case being accepted you are still looked as a burden!  Please don’t select this route. What ever situation you are experiencing in Iran is thousands times better than that.

And quick side note, Those who have migrated tend to falsly showing their condition much better than it really is. Don’t fall with that.

Still, if you are determent, invest in your self and remember there is no easy way to get your life a lot better without efforts and diligence.