# How can I get out of Iran?

Tags: germany, immigration, canada, sweden

I own a bachelor's degree in Software Engineering, and currently work as an IT expert in a private company in Iran. Considering that my dear country, Iran, is very isolated right now (and as it seems, it will remain under crippling sanctions for the foreseeable future), how can I get out of Iran and immigrate to Europe (Germany, Sweden, etc) or Canada? I'm 27, single and I have an intermediate level of English. Where should I start and what should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Why have you posted the same question twice?

Comment: @Traveller *Probably* because they went back in the browser and pressed "Post" a second time.  The system does warn you - but it doesn't prevent you doing so.  I have flagged for moderator attention (can't "close as duplicate" because the other question doesn't have an answer).

Comment: To all: please answer at https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/19862/how-can-i-get-out-of-iran (I'm sure it's much easier for the mods if they can just delete one question, rather than have to merge answers).